# How to efficiently delete the last line of a multiline string when the line is empty/blank?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete blank line at the bottom from the each sqlcmd output files, provided other vendor.

```
$List=Get-ChildItem * -include *.csv
foreach($file in $List) {
    $data = Get-Content $file                   
    $name = $file.name
    $length = $data.length -1                   
    $data[$length] = $null                      
    $data | Out-File $name -Encoding utf8 
}
```

It takes bit long time to remove the blank line. Anyone knows a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `Get-Content -Raw` to load files as a whole, as a *single string* into memory and operating on that string will give you the greatest speed boost.**

While that isn't always an option depending on file size, you mention sqlcmd files, which can be assumed to be small enough.

Note:

- By *blank line* I mean a line that is either *completely empty* or contains *whitespace* (other than newlines) only.
- The trimmed string will not have a final terminating newline following the last line, but if you pass it to `Set-Content` (or `Out-File`), one will be appended by default; use `-NoNewline` to suppress that, but not that especially on Unix-like platforms even the last line of text files is expected to have a trailing newline.
- Trailing (or leading) whitespace on a *non-blank* line is by design *not* trimmed, except where noted.
- The solutions use the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), which operates on [*regexes* (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions).

**Remove all *trailing* blank lines**:

<sup>Note: If you really want to remove only the *last* line if it happens to be blank, see the second-to-last solution below.</sup>

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '\r?\n\s*$'
```

In the context of your command (slightly modified):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sqlcmd | ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) -replace '\r?\n\s*$' |
   Set-Content $_.FullName -Encoding utf8 -WhatIf # save back to same file
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

**If it's acceptable / desirable to also trim trailing whitespace from the last *non-blank* line**, you can more simply write:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file).TrimEnd()
```

---

**Remove *all* blank lines**, wherever they occur in the file:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '(?m)\A\s*\r?\n|\r?\n\s*$'
```

Here's a conceptually much simpler version that operates on the *array* of lines output by `Get-Content` *without* `-Raw` (and also returns an array), but it performs much worse.

```
@(Get-Content $file) -notmatch '^\s*$'
```

<sup>Do not combine this with `Set-Content` / `Out-Content` `-NoNewline`, as that will concatenate the lines stored in the array elements directly, without line breaks between them. Without `-NoNewline`, you'll invariably get a terminating newline after the last line.</sup>

---

**Remove only the *last* line *if it is blank***:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '\r?\n[ \t]*\Z'
```

Note:

- `[ \t]` matches spaces and tabs, whereas `\s` more generally matches all forms of Unicode whitespace, including that outside the ASCII range.
- An optional trailing newline at the very end of the file (to terminate the last line) is *not* considered a blank line in this case - whether such a newline is present or not does not make a difference.

---

***Unconditionally* remove the *last* line**, whether it is blank or not:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '\r?\n[^\n]*\Z'
```

Note:

- An optional trailing newline at the very end of the file (to terminate the last line) is *not* considered a blank line in this case - whether such a newline is present or not does not make a difference.
- If you want to **remove the last *non-blank* line**, use
  `(Get-Content -Raw $file).TrimEnd() -replace '\r?\n[^\n]*\Z'`

Comment: My pleasure, @Sachiko.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing with this line. you will not have blank lines in your array value $data.

```
$data = get-content $file.FullPath | Where-Object {$_.trim() -ne "" }
```

Comment: Note that this will replace *all* blank lines in a text file, even if they appear in the middle.

Comment: I agree with @Bacon Bits, this will remove all empty lines, to remove just the trailing (`.TrimEnd()`) and/or leading (`.TrimStart()`) empty lines, you can simply do: `$data = (get-content $file.FullPath -All).Trim()`

Comment: I think you meant `-Raw`, not `-All`, @iRon. `.TrimEnd()` is certainly very simple, but note that it will also trim any trailing whitespace from the last _non-blank_ line - which may or not be acceptable. If it is, it is probably the fastest PowerShell-only solution. As for this answer (leaving aside that it does something different than asked, as stated): Line-by-line reading with `Get-Content` combined with the pipeline and `Where-Object` makes this a very slow solution (even if it is faster than the one in the question).